# How to clone Windows Mixed Reality boundaries between devices?

Tags: windows, virtual-reality, hololens

I have two computers with identical hardware and that are using WMR helmets (Samsung Odyssey).
I want to setup WMR boundaries on one of the PC and then clone it to the other one - so both of them should work identically in the same room.

Backuping and restoring `C:\ProgramData\WindowsHolographicDevices\` on single PC is working and I am almost sure that all data is stored there, but after the deployment to the second PC the data is ignored and the new setup is required.
Checked on windows 10 1803 and 1809.